# Error installing chaincode on HyperLedger fabric

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm working on this tutorial http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html on a virtual machine Ubuntu 14.04 and I run the script
`./byfn.sh -m up` to bring up the network. When I run this to install the chaincode:

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error installing chaincode code mycc:1.0(chaincode /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mycc.1.0 exists))
```

How can I fix this?

Note: I also run `docker exec -it cli bash`

Comment: Can you please add logs of the peer container?

Comment: you mean this: http://prntscr.com/gtzd3a  ??

Comment: Did you already have the chaincode installed? The error messages seems to indicate so....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, while I'm not 100% sure, since there is not enough information provided. So based on your logs snapshot provided in the comment and based on the error you've got:

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error installing chaincode code mycc:1.0(chaincode /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mycc.1.0 exists))

You trying to install chaincode with name which overlaps name of the chaincode installed by `byfn.sh` script. You can see in [script.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/first-network/scripts/script.sh#L119):

Try to change chaincode name in install command, to something different, e.g.:

```
peer chaincode install -n myNewCC -v 1.0 -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02
```

An alternative could be to disable execution of `script.sh`, however you will have to initialize and create the channel yourself. See [here](http://peer%20chaincode%20install%20-n%20mycc%20-v%201.0%20-p%20github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02).

Comment: Alternatively, you can also install the chaincode with the same but with a different version. This will essentially start a new chaincode container and should remove the error. You can also try stopping and removing the `mycc` container by executing `docker stop <container-id>` and then `docker rm <container-id>`. You can get container-ids by doing `docker ps -a`.

Comment: @jarvis yes your are correct, nice add-on, thanks for expanding on my answer :)